# what does 'work through an algorithm by hand' mean?

Tags: algorithm, bubble-sort

I'm doing this assignment and I don't understand the wording. Do you think it means to write in pseudocode or write a paragraph? Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: This appears to be copy-pasted from somewhere (e.g., https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/consider-following-vector-integers-2-12-1-7-9-9-1-2-3-4-5-6-7--hand-work-standard-bubble-s-q56587395).  We require you to credit the source of all copied material: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.

Comment: @D.W. I didn't copy-paste from that site. They copied from me. This is in fact a snip from my university's coursework assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means to describe the algorithm with words and draw the array values in each step. Here is an example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Answer (score 1):

Before executing the algorithm, the array is:

```
4  2 12  1  7  9  9
```

After executing the algorithm, the array is:

```
1  2  4  7  9  9 12
```

During the execution of the algorithm, the array slowly changes from what is was before, to what it will be after. Your assignment requires you to show all the intermediate steps.

For instance, the very first step of execution will be "compare element at position 0 with position 1; if element at position 1 is lower, then swap the two elements". The first two elements are 4 and 2; 2 is lower; hence they should be swapped; the resulting array is:

```
2  4 12  1  7  9  9
```

Then the second step will be "compare elements at position 1 and 2", which are 4 and 12; etc.